# What's the best option to close a GUI with the same key that opened it (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, lua, fivem

so, I'm trying to make some edits to an existing FiveM inventory script that opens a GUI and closes it using Javascript

**part of lua code when opening the inventory:**

```lua
if not IsPlayerDead(PlayerId()) then
            DisableControlAction(0, 37, true)
            if IsDisabledControlJustPressed(1, Config.OpenControl) and GetLastInputMethod(0) then 
            -- Config.OpenControl here is the same as the closing key which is ( TAB ↹ )
                    openInventory()
```

**Javascript code snippets:**

( I tried adding a variable and set it to True when the GUI opens )

```js
// var inventoryOpen = true;

window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    if (event.data.action == "display") {
        // inventoryOpen = true;
        type = event.data.type
        disabled = false;
```

( Tried setting the variable to false when the closeinventory() function is called )

```js
function closeInventory() {
    $(".ui").fadeOut();
    $.post("http://pb-inventory/NUIFocusOff", JSON.stringify({}));
    // inventoryOpen = false;
}
```

( and this is when the Closing key is pressed )

```js
$("body").on("keyup", function (key) {
        if (Config.closeKeys.includes(key.which)) { // Config.closeKeys here is 9 which is the TAB key ↹
            // if (inventoryOpen == true) {
                closeInventory();
            // }
        }
    });
```

So when I tried the commented code above, the Gui starts being glitchy and kept closing after opening.

Comment: yea, that's not pure JavaScript.  `$(".ui").fadeOut();` is jQuery.  their UI code can be confusing.  you'll need to show like half the code, 'cuz there's no way to tell where the error is from this tiny bit.

Comment: here is the full script - it's not that long: https://pastecode.io/s/rJbY25UA8j

Comment: you want me to enable JavaScript to view text on a website that was domain-registered with flippin' godaddy two months ago?  Try a website that's more trustworthy and well known, such as pastebin or github gist.

Comment: you don't need to enable javascript on that site in order to see the code. Anyway here's a gist link: https://gist.github.com/DirtyGaming/668c22d01f0669a2fb23f5328e449260